# Installation of Anaconda 2020.02 fails under Windows with activated WSL

Tags: python, anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to install Anaconda 2020.02 under Windows 10 and it hangs during the installation process at the point when it tries to extract “anaconda-2020.02-py37_0.tar.bz2”.

The only peculiarity of my machine is that I have Windows Subsystem for Linux activated (on which I installed Ubuntu with it’s own copy of Anaconda).

Any idea if this could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Were you installing it from the command line?

Comment: No, I double click on the windows installer. Why?

Comment: @user3877351 Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I waited for a long time until the installation passed that point that looked like it hung. It doesn't really hang. It just takes a really long time.